# FireBase Server Data Extraction To Use its Values in code?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to Get Some Data From my **realtime Data Server** in Fire Base and am not quite sure why it's not working,

I'm Logging The User Date When Entered into my app and Comparing it With The Previous Date Saved And Based On That I save the new date and take action, But It Isn't Quit Working. I Beleive That the issue is from The Data Extraction/Getting Code, And the issue is that I'm in need of updating the Date Each Time user Is entered into My App.

This is My Main Activity And it's In Kotlin.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var databaseref: DatabaseReference
    val currentDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
    private lateinit var listener: ChangeTasks

    fun setListener(listener: ChangeTasks) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    // Retrieve year, month, day, hour, minute, and second
    val month = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 // Months are zero-based
    val day = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)


    // val day2 = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

var updating = false
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)
        binding.BottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)
        databaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Last Time In App")
        listener = object : ChangeTasks {
            override fun chnageDishesTasks() {
                // Implement the logic for changing dishes tasks
                // You can updat e UI in another fragment here
            }

            override fun chnageTableTasks() {
                // Implement the logic for changing table tasks
                // You can update UI in another fragment here
            }
        }

// Define your data
        setListener(listener)
        getdataFireBase()
    }

    private fun getdataFireBase() {
        var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        databaseref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (!updating) {

                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        val lastTimeInAppSnapshot = snapshot.child("Last Time In App")
                        Log.d("Maher", "Its Snap Exists $snapshot")

                        if (lastTimeInAppSnapshot.exists()) {
                            Log.d("Maher", "Its Node Exists $snapshot")

                            val dayValue = lastTimeInAppSnapshot.child("Day").getValue(Int::class.java)
                            if (dayValue != null) {

                                if (day > dayValue) {
                                    Log.d("Maher", "Its Greater $snapshot")

                                    listener.chnageDishesTasks()
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        applicationContext,
                                        "Date Has Changed",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                    ).show()
                                    listener.chnageTableTasks()
                                    var data = mapOf("Day" to day, "Month" to month)
                                    database.child("Last Time In App").child("Day").setValue(day)
                                    updating = true

                                } else {
                                    Log.d("Maher", "Its Not Greater $snapshot")

                                    var data = mapOf("Day" to day, "Month" to month)
                                    database.child("Last Time In App").child("Day").setValue(day)
                                    updating = true

                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.d("Maher", "Its Null $snapshot")

                                var data = mapOf("Day" to day, "Month" to month)
                                database.child("Last Time In App").child("Day").setValue(day)
                                updating = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.e("Massa", "Database operation cancelled: ${error.message}")

            }
        })
    }


    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_biking -> onCyclingClicked()
        R.id.nav_running -> onRunningClicked()
        else -> false
    }

    private fun onCyclingClicked(): Boolean {
        supportFragmentManager.commit {
            replace(R.id.frame_Content, Cyclingfragmenr())
        }
        return true
    }

    private fun onRunningClicked(): Boolean {
        supportFragmentManager.commit {
            replace(R.id.frame_Content, FragnetRunning())
        }
        return true
    }

    interface ChangeTasks {
        fun chnageDishesTasks()
        fun chnageTableTasks()
    }
}
```

I tried This code above and Expected To See my Realtime Server Updating Each Time i enter the app , But Sadly It Did Not Work.

Comment: There's **a lot** that could be going on here. To increase the chances that someone can help, I recommend debugging the problem locally first and then sharing the results of that. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: And since this on Android: the docs have a great page on [debugging your Android app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @AlexMamo, I am getting The Value Of the snapshot, And it Retuning The Date Of a previous Login, But now it's not even Updating, I and chat Gpt Are very confused since my Code Is Supposed To Work, My Fire base Data is as follows,  under it IS my Root Nod and Under it is my 'Last Time In App ' Node .and then i have 'Day:' and 'Month:', I hope This Made it Clear.